# Algorithm to parse strings up to and including number

Tags: java, algorithm

This was part of a problem in a coding challenge interview I recently had.  I came up with a hacky solution, but I am sure there is a better way.

One of the requirements was to find a set of strings up to and including the number. The letter after the number indicates a subset of the main group. The groups from the below string would be the strings "ford1", "ford333, "ford4", "ford2"

String codes = "ford1, ford333, ford4, ford4a, ford4b, ford1a, ford2, ford333a";

Note that you are not allowed to sort the strings once they are parsed.

---

*Input specification:* The input consists of a single string, which contains comma separated substrings. Each substring begins with **one or more letters**, followed by **one or more digits**, followed by **zero or more letters**. Here's an example input:

```
String codes = "ford1, ford333, ford4, ford4a, ford4b, ford1a, ford2, ford333a";
```

*Rules:* the algorithm must find every substring that does not have letters after the digits.

*Output specification:* The output shall be a list of substrings that conform to the rules. The output does not need to be in sorted order. The output for the example is:

```
"ford1", "ford333", "ford4", "ford2"
```

Comment: What is your question? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The question is how to parse the string.  I gave inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify the description of the algorithm, but a good algorithm question should also show your code. For all we know, you already have the best possible algorithm. But maybe someone can show you how to polish the code, so that although the algorithm is unchanged, the code looks cleaner.

Comment: @vivek_23 Sorry buddy.  didn't mean to ignore you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex.

```
String codes = "ford1, ford333, ford4, ford4a, ford4b, ford1a, ford2, ford333a";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+[0-9]+)(,|$)");

Matcher m = pat.matcher(codes);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output:

```
ford1
ford333
ford4
ford2
```

If you don't like the reliance on the position of the comma then this pattern also seems to work

```
([a-z]+[0-9]++)([^a-z]|$)
```

Comment: Slick.  Can you please explain this part of the expression "(,|$)".  I can see that it groups the results.  I'm just not sure how this combination of characters achieves the task.

Comment: I can only guess the first "command" is look for a coma, then group with the $.

Comment: The first group `([a-z]+[0-9]+)` matches a string of 1 or more characters followed by 1 or more digits. The 2nd capturing group `(,|$)`, which we ignore in the output, specifies that the next character has to be either a comma or ('|') the end of the string ('$').

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. What was you hacky solution by the way? Posting it in the question would help.

As per my understanding, you want to group the codes which do not have an alphabet after the last digit. If that's correct, then here is a basic code I can think of to handle it.

```
    String codes = "ford1, ford333, ford4, ford4a, ford4b, ford1a, ford2, ford333a";
    String[] codeArr = codes.split(",");
    List<String> group = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String code : codeArr) {
        code = code.trim();
        for(int i=0; i<code.length(); i++) {
            // Skip over all non digit char
            while(i<code.length() && !Character.isDigit(code.charAt(i)))
                i++;

            // reached a digit. Skip over all digits
            while(i<code.length() && Character.isDigit(code.charAt(i)))
                i++;

            if(i == code.length())
                // reached end of code i.e. no letter after the digits
                group.add(code);
        }
    }
```

If this is not what is expected, then please clarify your question further and add your hacky code.